# Send data from a background thread to the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a C# server from the main application and I would like to pass the message received from the server thread to the main thread. The server should be running on the background for new connections. Every time there is a new connection the server should pass the message received to the main app. How can let the main app know when the message is received? and how can pass the message from the server thread to the main when there is a new connection?

Main application

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
        TCPServer Server = new TCPServer(); //start running the server
        //get the message (Server.message) when a client sent it to the server
        //TODO process the message
    }
```

TCP server

```
class TCPServer
    {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;
        private String message;

        public TCPServer()
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3200);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.listenThread.Start();

    }

 //starts the tcp listener and accept connections
    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Listening...");
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Client connected");


            //create a thread to handle communication 
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }


    //Read the data from the client
    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {

        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client; //start the client
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream(); //get the stream of data for network access

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true) 
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0) //if we receive 0 bytes
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server 


          break;
                }
                //message has successfully been received
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                message = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);

                //Reply
                byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("ACK");
                clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ACK");
                clientStream.Flush();
               }
            tcpClient.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
        }
```

Comment: Is this a multithreatened application?

Comment: it's threa**d**, not "threat".

Comment: There is the main and then the server that should run a new thread on the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already well supported by TcpListener, use the BeginAcceptTcpClient() method instead.  When you call it from the main thread of a WPF or Winforms app then the callback will run on the same main thread automatically.  The same applies to its BeginReceive() method.  Internally it uses the dispatcher loop to get the callback method activated, pretty similar to the way a class like BackgroundWorker and the C# v5 async/await keywords work.

This saves you from the hassle of starting end terminating your own thread and ensuring you marshal back properly.  And significantly cutting down on the resource usage of your program.  Highly recommended.

Comment: Do you mean to run the TcpListener from the WPF and avoid to use the TCPServer class? or create a new class with the TCPListener? Any reference or example will help.

Answer (score 0):

A Queue is the answer. Specifically in this case a [Concurrent Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Your socket thread puts messages into the queue. Your worker thread(s) poll the queue and pulls work items out.

For socket based applications, this pattern is very, very common.

Alternatively, you can [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) against the system thread pool, and let it manage the work load.

Note: You're in multi-threaded land now. You'll need to read about synchronization and other issues that are going to arise. Failure to do this means your app will have very weird bugs.